# Minimum Signal Current for DALI Driver

Tags: led, dali

I was looking at the specifications for DALI drivers and apparently the nominal current usage is 2mA/driver for the dimming signal. Does anyone know what the minimum current is?

I have a 12V/1mA supply and am wondering if this would work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **maximum**, not nominal, current draw for a driver (which are usually mains powered, this doesn't apply to bus powered) is 2mA, this is over the voltage range 0 to 22.5V and the temperature range. It applies when the driver is not transmitting, because when transmitting the driver pulls the line down to the current limit of the supply, maximum 250mA.
The minimum current consumption when not transmitting is 10uA over the voltage range of (threshold voltage of the receiver) to 22.5V.

Additionally, there are requirements on power supplies in IEC62386-101 which you should have if you are working with DALI. 12V does meet the output voltage minimum of 12.0V over full input voltage range, load range, temperature but the supply must produce a guaranteed minimum supply current of 8.0mA at 12.0V over the temperature range.

Whilst most LED drivers and other such control gear are mains powered, it is allowable to have bus powered gear, and many control devices such as sensors are bus powered. These do not have an additional mains or other power input and draw their power from the DALI bus. In that case they are allowed to draw nearly 250mA but must specify what they draw when not transmitting so that a system designer can specify the power supply correctly.

Comment: Thank you this is great! So a DALI driver could effectively receive and decode my 1mA 12V digital signal since it is above 10uA, or will it not work because I’m below 8mA? The application is a functionality tester that simply sends: “dim-up,” “dim-down,” and “lowest lumen level” commands

Comment: No, it’s likely that 1mA won’t be enough for the driver to see the line as high. 1mA is a very small current limit, why is it so low? To meet the spec it should be 8mA. The majority of drivers I’ve tested draw 1.0 to 1.6mA at 16V, to give you an idea, and that’s to satisfy their input optocoupler CTR spec.

Comment: Ah ok shoot. To be honest, poor design lol. I have a 24VDC source that is continuously running through a 12kOhm resistor in series with a 12VDC Zener. The driver then sees the 12V across the zener with a max of 1mA. In the future I want to add a SSR to the configuration and up the current, but this is what I have to work with for now.

Comment: Hmm I’m putting that 12V signal through a BJT to achieve the high-low switching functionality. The base is receiving 10mA, so my total might actually be up to 11mA now. Better? Lol

Comment: @cdubs If you ask that as a seperate question, you could include the schematic for clarity and get more suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, thanks